# Join a query result set with an existing table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query result set like this:

```
value | id 
500   | 1
400   | 1
300   | 2
```

and a product table:

```
product_name | id 
product_1    | 1 
product_2    | 2 
product_5    | 3
product_6    | 4 
product_9    | 5 
product_0    | 6
```

Now I want to find the **product_name** from product table for every row in query result set and join the result to look like following:

The result after joining should be following:

```
product_name | id | value
product_1    | 1  | 500
product_1    | 1  | 400
product_2    | 2  | 300
```

I am getting confused how to use left join to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd join based on the value that's common between the two tables; in this case, it's `id`.

It doesn't seem like you want any NULL values for `value`, so you wouldn't use a `LEFT JOIN`; you'd want an `INNER JOIN` instead.

This would get you pretty much what you want; bear in mind that this is untested.

```
SELECT p.product_name, qr.id, value
FROM product p
INNER JOIN query_result_set qr ON qr.id = p.id
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Also, your expectations are wrong - `product_5` has an id of 3, so it wouldn't appear in this join result.